# I use batch = 5 in tensorflow during training phase, why I cant use only batch = 1 test in tensorflowjs？

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I train the GAN model in tensorflow with batchsize=5,so the generator input size is [5,imagesize,imagesize,3].After training,I convert tensorflow model into the tensorflowjs model.

So,I load the model by `loadFrozenModel`.Then use `model.predict` to predict an image.However, the shape of dict['concat'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [5,512,512,12], but was [1,512,512,12].
How to solve this problem?I use mini-batch in traning phase in tensorflow,and only predict an image with one input not 5 inputs in tensorflowjs

[Figure 1. the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Nwp.png)

Comment: You simply are not giving the right shape to your tensor input. Could you show your js code ?

Comment: the js tensor input is 4 image,then I concat them,so the input shape is[1,512,512,12]

Comment: if you show the code, it will be easier to tell how to fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you set the batch size explicitly as part of the input shape in your training job, e.g.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[5, 512, 512, 12])
```

Instead you should leave the batch size unspecified, like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 512, 512, 12])
```

That way the graph will work with whatever batch size you give it, both at training and at inference time.

If you have code that needs to know the batch size explicitly, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/faq#how_do_i_build_a_graph_that_works_with_variable_batch_sizes) for some tips.

Comment: However,I use  tf.nn.conv2d_transpose in my network. The third parameter of this function is output_shape. According to your speech, the first dimension of the input data is changed to None, then the first dimension of ouput_shape also becomes None, but it cannot be compiled successfully.

Comment: TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 4, 4, 512]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Comment: Yep, that situation requires determining the batch size at runtime.  See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/faq#how_do_i_build_a_graph_that_works_with_variable_batch_sizes, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/833, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822411/conv2d-transpose-is-dependent-on-batch-size-when-making-predictions.